# Confused about safari viewport on iPhone 7

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, viewport

From what [I have read](http://mydevice.io/devices/) the viewport for the iPhone 7 is supposed to be 375 x 667.

I have a just unboxed iPhone 7 in front of me with Safari open. When I run window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight I get 320 x 460. This matches visually with what I would expect the website I am developing to look like if the viewport was actually 320 x 460.

The height is partially explained by the task bar, address bar and tool bar (but 247 pixels?) The width I don't get at all.

So what is going on here?

Edit: I have this viewport meta data

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
```

Edit 2: Discovered I had the display zoom set to zoomed.

So now my question is why? This was a new iPhone. Is it standard to have the viewport set to zoomed?

Edit: Turns out the iphone had been turned on before I got it for testing.

Comment: You are asked when you set up the device if you would like to use "Zoomed" or "Standard"

Comment: @JamesWebster Thanks. (see my edit) If you put that as an answer then I'll accept it.

Comment: OK so my eyes are horrible in a short-sighted kind of way, but I hate people whose eyes are horrible in a need-to-zoom kind of way :-( SO much more development work

Answer (score 1):

You are asked when you set up the device if you would like to use "Zoomed" or "Standard"